# PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS

Tags: protocol-buffers, blockchain

I'm trying to install Open Transactions, the open-source project, on a debian 8. I've installed all the dependencies and am having an issue when compiling (make). The following error is showing at my terminal, even though i made sure to install the protobuf project:

```
In file included from /root/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTStoragePB.hpp:64:0,
                 from /root/opentxs/src/core/OTStorage.cpp:47:
/root/opentxs/build/src/core/otprotob/Generics.pb.h:501:6: error: "PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS" is not defined [-Werror=undef]
 #if !PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS
      ^
In file included from /root/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTStoragePB.hpp:65:0,
                 from /root/opentxs/src/core/OTStorage.cpp:47:
/root/opentxs/build/src/core/otprotob/Markets.pb.h:2062:6: error: "PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS" is not defined [-Werror=undef]
 #if !PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS
      ^
In file included from /root/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTStoragePB.hpp:66:0,
                 from /root/opentxs/src/core/OTStorage.cpp:47:
/root/opentxs/build/src/core/otprotob/Bitcoin.pb.h:833:6: error: "PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS" is not defined [-Werror=undef]
 #if !PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS
      ^
In file included from /root/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTStoragePB.hpp:67:0,
                 from /root/opentxs/src/core/OTStorage.cpp:47:
/root/opentxs/build/src/core/otprotob/Moneychanger.pb.h:1026:6: error: "PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS" is not defined [-Werror=undef]
 #if !PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS
      ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
src/core/CMakeFiles/opentxs-core.dir/build.make:1368: recipe for target 'src/core/CMakeFiles/opentxs-core.dir/OTStorage.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/opentxs-core.dir/OTStorage.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/opentxs/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:586: recipe for target 'src/core/CMakeFiles/opentxs-core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/opentxs-core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/opentxs/build'
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this? Couldn't find any help online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 and I fix it as you said . But I am just writing to explain more the issue. 
So , After googling the error I found this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gem5-gpu-dev/EI0OqeSPXzU)  . In which they describe that the problem arises from the fact that the google coders are relying on the fact that the C++ standard allows you to treat an undefined preprocessor symbol as evaluating to 0. So there is a bunch of #if directives testing the value of `PROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS` when it hasn’t been defined anywhere; this is legal and should be treated as if it’s a zero. 
I fixed this by adding `-DPROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS=0` into CCFLAGS in the the top-level SConstruct and CXXFLAGS in src/SConscript (CXXFLAGS) and that seemed to catch it.

So to fix this , you should add this line in the CMakeList.txt that you find in opentxs main folder :

> add_definitions(-DPROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS=0)

And don't forget to repeat the `cmake` step .

Hope this is more clear and helpful .

Comment: Even if this use of "implied 0" is correct the check is done in place where it is the only condition. So, it could have been written as `#ifndef` with no loss. Pity that they didn't do it so...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding this line at the top of the CMakelists.txt

```
add_definitions(-DPROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS=0)
```