# OpenTransactions/Protobuf ambiguous error

Tags: transactions, protocol-buffers, blockchain

I'm trying to compile OpenTransactions but i had to install some other projects first, the compiler stopped at a certain point and showed me this log of errors:

```
[ 91%] Building CXX object src/client/CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir

/OpenTransactions.cpp.o
cd  /home/otx/opentxs/build/src/client && /usr/bin/c++    -DCHAISCRIPT_NO_THREADS -DEXPORT="" -DOT_CASH_USING_LUCRE  -DOT_CRYPTO_SUPPORTED_KEY_RSA -DOT_CRYPTO_SUPPORTED_KEY_SECP256K1  -DOT_CRYPTO_USING_LIBSECP256K1 -DOT_CRYPTO_USING_OPENSSL  -DOT_CRYPTO_USING_TREZOR -DOT_CRYPTO_WITH_BIP32 -DOT_CRYPTO_WITH_BIP39  -DOT_PREFIX_PATH=\"/usr/local\" -DPROTOBUF_INLINE_NOT_IN_HEADERS=NULL  -Dopentxs_client_EXPORTS -std=c++11 -pthread -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wextra  -pedantic -Wno-missing-braces -Wcast-align -Wctor-dtor-privacy  -Wdisabled-optimization -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs  -Wswitch-default -Wold-style-cast -Wredundant-decls -Woverloaded-virtual  -Wmissing-declarations -Wunused-macros -Wundef -Wformat=2  -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wnoexcept -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wlogical-op  -Wuseless-cast -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -I/home/otx/opentxs/build/deps/include  -isystem /home/otx/opentxs/src/../deps -isystem  /home/otx/opentxs/src/../deps/ChaiScript/include -isystem  /home/otx/opentxs/src/../deps/lucre/include  -I/home/otx/opentxs/build/src/../include  -I/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include -isystem  /home/otx/opentxs/deps/czmq/include    -o  CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir/OpenTransactions.cpp.o -c  /home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp
/home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:  In member function ‘opentxs::OT_API::ClaimSet  opentxs::OT_API::GetClaims(const opentxs::Nym&) const’:
/home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:4514:38:  error: call of overloaded ‘OTData(google::protobuf::int64)’ is  ambiguous
             OTData start(item.start());
                                      ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:4514:38: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/Identifier.hpp:43:0,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/Contract.hpp:45,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/crypto/Credential.hpp:45,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/crypto/NymParameters.hpp:46,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/client/OpenTransactions.hpp:44,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:43:
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:60:12: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(opentxs::OTData&&)
     EXPORT OTData(OTData&& other);
            ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:57:12: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(const opentxs::OTData&)
     EXPORT OTData(const OTData& source);
            ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:55:21: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(int64_t)
     EXPORT explicit OTData(const int64_t num);
                     ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:54:21: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(uint32_t)
     EXPORT explicit OTData(const uint32_t num);
                     ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:4515:34:  error: call of overloaded ‘OTData(google::protobuf::int64)’ is  ambiguous
             OTData end(item.end());
                                  ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:4515:34: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/Identifier.hpp:43:0,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/Contract.hpp:45,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/crypto/Credential.hpp:45,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/crypto/NymParameters.hpp:46,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/client/OpenTransactions.hpp:44,
                 from /home/otx/opentxs/src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp:43:
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:60:12: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(opentxs::OTData&&)
     EXPORT OTData(OTData&& other);
            ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:57:12: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(const opentxs::OTData&)
     EXPORT OTData(const OTData& source);
            ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:55:21: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(int64_t)
     EXPORT explicit OTData(const int64_t num);
                     ^
/home/otx/opentxs/src/../include/opentxs/core/OTData.hpp:54:21: note: opentxs::OTData::OTData(uint32_t)
     EXPORT explicit OTData(const uint32_t num);
                     ^
src/client/CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir/build.make:2472:  recipe for target  'src/client/CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir/OpenTransactions.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/client/CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir/OpenTransactions.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/otx/opentxs/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1044: recipe for target 'src/client/CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/client/CMakeFiles/opentxs-client.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/otx/opentxs/build'
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I had run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474091/protobuf-inline-not-in-headers) first and solved it(i think). Anyone has any insights on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably related to the compiler, but mine (gcc 4.9) did get stuck at this point because it did not know which constructor to call for, so what should have been done is casting the int64 to the argument of both lines (OTData start and OTData end in lines 4514 & 4515 in  src/client/OpenTransactions.cpp)
This has been fixed today thanks to Chris Odom in this [push](https://github.com/Open-Transactions/opentxs/pull/649/files).